# AngularJS - Auto assigning incremental label to a list of items

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I have a list of items that I am publishing using ng-repeat.  I get only one variable from the Rest API response and that is Product Name.  My list of products looks like this

iPhone  7
iPad 2
Samsung Galaxy
..
..
..

This is a dynamic list and I would like to assign a numeric series to the list so that it looks like this

1. iPhone 7
2. iPad 2
3. Samsung Galaxy
4. ..
5. ..

and so on.  How do I do it

Comment: Ng-repeat inside an ordered list item should do it

Comment: Can you please provide a code example?

Comment: <ol><li ng-repeat="brand in vm.brands" ng-bind="brand.name"></li></ol>

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, hope it helps and gets you going in the right direction.

```js
function exampleController($scope) {
  $scope.phones = [{
    model: 'iphone'
  }, {
    model: 'iPad 2'
  }, {
    model: 'Samsung Galaxy'
  }];
}

angular
  .module('example', [])
  .controller('exampleController', exampleController);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div class="container-fluid" ng-app="example">
  <div class="container" ng-controller="exampleController">
    <div class="row">
      <ol>
        <li ng-repeat="phone in phones track by $index" ng-bind="phone.model"></li>
      </ol>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

With slighter modification from what @alphapilgrim has mentioned, you can use `$index` to get the sequence / serial number.As it starts with 0 and +1 for every increment for right sequence.

You can use this technique on any HTML tag unlike `<li> & <ol>` to generate serial numbers.

```js
function exampleController($scope) {
  $scope.phones = [{
    model: 'iphone'
  }, {
    model: 'iPad 2'
  }, {
    model: 'Samsung Galaxy'
  }];
}

angular
  .module('example', [])
  .controller('exampleController', exampleController);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div class="container-fluid" ng-app="example">
  <div class="container" ng-controller="exampleController">
    <div class="row">
      
        <p ng-repeat="phone in phones track by $index" >{{$index+1}}.{{phone.model}}</p>
      
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```